# Adjust fieldset width and adjust to center

Tags: sencha-touch, width, center, padding, fieldset

I am just a beginner for sencha touch technology. Now I got a simple question. How can I adjust the fieldset width and align to center only? I only get the fieldset which are setting for fullscreen only. Please guild me a solution.

Here my javascript

```
          items:[{
                xtype:'fieldset',
                title :'Please enter your password key',

                centered: true,
                width: 30,

                items:[{
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name : 'password',
                        label: 'password',
                        width : 400,



                    }]






              }],
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Hard Coded values in the code, that's  bad when you making the application for multiple resolution

Please try the code shown  below   it works for me

```
layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            pack: 'center',
            align: 'center'
        },
    items:[{
                xtype:'fieldset',
                title :'Please enter your password key',

                //centered: true,
                //width: 30,

                items:[{
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name : 'password',
                        label: 'password',
                        //width : 400,
               }]
     }]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
items:[{
              xtype:'fieldset',
              title :'Please enter your password key',

              centered: true, // using this you can align fieldset to center
              width: '80%',   // using this you can give any width to it in percentage

              items:[{
                     xtype: 'passwordfield',
                     name : 'password',
                     label: 'password',      
                     }]  
              }],
```

OR

```
items:[{
              xtype:'fieldset',
              title :'Please enter your password key',

             // centered: true,
              margin: '10%',
              width: '80%',
              height: '20%',

              items:[{
                     xtype: 'passwordfield',
                     name : 'password',
                     label: 'password',  
                     }]

              }],
```

hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

try

style: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '100px'  }

Answer (score 0):

in ST2
place it inside the container like this

```
{
  xtype: 'container',
  centered: true,
  items:{
       xtype: 'fieldset',
       items :[
         //your items here
       ]
  }
}
```